# Facebook Canvas App Error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to show/hide a div tag with respect to if user has liked a certain page. Here is my code:

```
var token='';

var userId="";
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '551162755011927',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0',
          scope: 'user_likes', 
        });

       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

           console.log("Token:"+response.authResponse.accessToken);
           console.log("User ID:"+response.authResponse.userID);

           token=response.authResponse.accessToken;



       }); 


       FB.api(
       "/me/likes/PageName",
       function (response) {
       if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */

       console.log("User likey!");

       //document.getElementById('nolikey').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('likey').style.display = "block";

        }
        else
        {
        console.log("User no likey :("+response.error.message);

        document.getElementById('likey').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('nolikey').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
,{access_token: token});
```

I keep getting this error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving the `FB.api` call which checks the like to be inside the callback for getLoginStatus - currently you are trying to call the API before checking you are logged in.

Comment: @madebydavid Not getting the same error anymore. Now it says :"(#114) An id must be a valid ID string (e.g., "123")"

Comment: Ahh, you need to pass the page ID to /me/likes not the name

Comment: Great! I'll write it up as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the code is calling the FB API before checking that the user is logged in and receiving the token variable, so you should move the `FB.api` call to be inside of the callback for `getLoginStatus`.

Also, when checking if a user has liked a page - you need to query by page ID, not by name.

Like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

    console.log("Token:"+response.authResponse.accessToken);
    console.log("User ID:"+response.authResponse.userID);

    token=response.authResponse.accessToken;

    var pageID = 123;

    FB.api(
        "/me/likes/" + pageID,
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                /* handle the result */
                console.log("User likey!");
                //document.getElementById('nolikey').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('likey').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                console.log("User no likey :("+response.error.message);
                document.getElementById('likey').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('nolikey').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    ,{access_token: token}); 

});
```